# Application using Python and Javascript

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, electron

I am creating a project that uses Electron to create the application interface (HTML, CSS, Javascript) and I am also using Selenium (Python) for the backend.

**Question 1)** How would I create a virtual environment for these 2 technologies? Since they are different.

**Question 2)** How would I communicate between these two? Basically I would need to send a string from Python to Javascript and vice versa.

**Question 3)** How would I transform this application that uses Python and Javascript into an executable? Since they are different.

**NOTE:** I want to use Selenium from Python, because I know more Python than Javascript.